# Why does this listings command keep giving me this error?

Tags: errors, listings

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\author{foobar}
\title{foofoofoo}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\lstset{basicstyle=\texttt} %THIS LINE
\section{Source Code}
I will admit that this code is {\it messy}.
\subsection{foo.c}
\lstinputlisting{foo.c}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand why that line makes `pdflatex` not compile; when I remove it, everything works fine.

It gives me this:

```
! Incomplete \ifmmode; all text was ignored after line
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Replace the `\texttt` by `\ttfamily` and `\it` should be either `\itshape messy` or `\textit{messy}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `\texttt` is a command that expects an argument, it won't find strange characters etc. in `listings` verbatim mode. It's not possible to give verbatim code as an argument to another command. This is why `\texttt{...}` must fail.

In order to achieve `typewriter` font, use `\ttfamily` to switch to this font. Note, this is an enduring switch (until another switch is applied), whereas `\texttt{...}` lasts only for the `{...}` - delimited argument.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\author{foobar}
\title{foofoofoo}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily} %THIS LINE
\section{Source Code}
I will admit that this code is {\textit{messy}}.
\subsection{foo.c}
\lstinputlisting{foo.c}
\end{document}
```

`foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why does texttt not work?

Comment: @occamsrazor: I explained and extended it on the top of my answer